# How many ways can 1...32 balls be placed inside 8 distinct boxes where each box has a capacity of 4?

Tags: combinatorics

The question asks that you can have a range of different number of indistinguishable balls from 1 to 32. How many ways are there to distribute them inside 8 distinct boxes? Each box has a maximum capacity of 4. 
I was trying to use stars and bars but the capacity restriction is really annoying. Is there any mathematical solution or the only way here is to enumerate? Thanks!

Comment: It's still stars and bars; it's just that the bars can have at most $4$ stars between them.

Comment: Just expand 
$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^8=x^{32}+8 x^{31}+36 x^{30}+120 x^{29}+330 x^{28}+784 x^{27}+1652 x^{26}+3144 x^{25}+5475
   x^{24}+8800 x^{23}+13140 x^{22}+18320 x^{21}+23940 x^{20}+29400 x^{19}+34000 x^{18}+37080
   x^{17}+38165 x^{16}+37080 x^{15}+34000 x^{14}+29400 x^{13}+23940 x^{12}+18320
   x^{11}+13140 x^{10}+8800 x^9+5475 x^8+3144 x^7+1652 x^6+784 x^5+330 x^4+120 x^3+36 x^2+8
   x+1$$ to get the generating function. Without the restriction on box sizes you would take powers of $(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)=1/(1-x)$ and get the stars and bars.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thanks for the clarification. But how do you actually modify the formula to account for the at most 4 stars between them? Thanks!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Would you please clarify how do you get the formula? And what does the x stands for? I'm familiar with the binominal coefficient form of stars and bars argument, namely, (n+k-1) choose (k-1) but has never seen the form using x. Thanks.

Comment: $x$ is just a placeholder. The coefficient of $x^n$ tells the number of ways of distributing $n$ balls into the 8 boxes, none with more than four. The connection to the generating function you are familiar with comes from the identity
$$(1-x)^{-k}=(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)^k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}x^n.$$ To prove that identity differentiate both sides of $$1/(1-x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$$ $k-1$ times.

Comment: If you have not heard of *generating functions* look up [this WP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function). See [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Examples_of_generating_functions_for_simple_sequences) in particular.